# How to filter products out with custom created field on catalog_product_entity

Tags: magento2, db-schema

I have added 2 fields in `db_schema.xml` there created on table `catalog_product_entity` the challenges for me now are I'm using the one field as custom state and this state is the field I need to filter on.

here is my code

```
$products = $this->productCollection->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter([
                [
                    'attribute' => 'status',
                    'eq' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED
                ],
            ])
            ->setPageSize($page_size)
            ->setCurPage($current_page);
```

The problem is coming when I'm adding the next filter like this

```
->addAttributeToFilter([
                    [
                        'attribute' => 'status',
                        'eq' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED
                    ],
[
                        'attribute' => 'my_state',
                        'nin' => 'custom-state'
                    ],
                ])
```

When I did it this way its tell me the attribute is invalid, but its exists in the table, I have doublet check my database tool

```
The "my_state" attribute name is invalid. Reset the name and try again
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove that newly added column filter from attribute filter as it's not attribute it's a field you have added in main catalog entity table and add the field filter condition.

So instead of

```
->addAttributeToFilter([
                [
                    'attribute' => 'status',
                    'eq' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED
                ],
                [
                    'attribute' => 'my_state',
                    'nin' => 'custom-state'
                ],
    ])
```

Change it to

```
->addAttributeToFilter([
                [
                    'attribute' => 'status',
                    'eq' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED
                ]
            ]);
->addFieldToFilter('my_state', 'nin'=>['custom-state']);
```

Upvote if it works!

Comment: Its not working, still say its can't find my field, and its exists in my table:

/var/www/project # bin/magento smartpack:product:sync In AbstractCollection.php line 1407:  The "wms_state" attribute name is invalid. Reset the name and try again.

Comment: You have used that wms_state in ->addFieldToFilter('my_state', 'nin'=>['wms_state']); like this right?

Comment: Also have you removed that from addAttributeToFilter? Try to add addFieldToSelect('wms_state')

Comment: When i add the "addFieldToSelect" its working so much I can see it in the output but same error when I add the "filter" function again, but one step closer

Comment: Use should use addFieldToSelect('wms_state')  first and then after add that filter condition by that way it should work.

Comment: Its shoud but not working, are there a raw-sql way to do the same?

Comment: Can you post you'r updated query with error.

Comment: Already post it, its the same error, its can find it :/